# How to Chunking large dissimilarity / distance matrices in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean-distance, chunking

I would like to cluster mix-type data that contains 50k rows and 10 features/columns. I am using R in my 64 bit PC. When I calculate dissimilarity / distance matrix with "daisy" function, I got "Error: cannot allocate vector of size X GB" error.

gower_dist <- daisy(df, metric = "gower").

This is the command to generate distance matrix. How to handle this script with chunks to avoid RAM error ?

Comment: And then? Write it to disk? How are you going to use it? Think about the next steps and the consequences of O(n²) memory, rather than short sighted hotfixes.

Comment: R is working on RAM. So when daisy function creates the matrix, It can not write directly to disk. (At least I could not find how to write directly to the disc). Since It tries to create the matrix in RAM, It gives error.

Comment: Yes. But even when putting them on disk, that won't get you much farther, that is what I am saying. You may be using the wrong approach for your data if you run out of memory already.